# Google Calendar Event Scheduled for Mon - Thurs

Tags: google-calendar

How do I create a Google Calendar event that occurs all year every Mon-Thurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In Google Calendar, click on the Create button.
2. Click on the "Repeat..." checkbox, and a popup box will appear.
3. In the "Repeat on" section, check the "M", "T", W", and "T" boxes.
4. In the "Ends" section, check the "On" radio box and select the date you want the event to end.  Since you said you want it to occur all year, you can select 12/31/2015.
5. Click the "Done" button.
6. Fill in the other event details.
7. Click the "Save" button.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow missed something before when I was trying to do this, but got it now.